# How to build an Azure Function with Cosmos DB Trigger?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-triggers

I am trying to develop in Azure portal an Azure Function (Node.js) that is triggered by Cosmos DB when create a doc. Azure documentation says that to do so, first i have to select "Cosmos db trigger" from templates, but no templates appear in my function... Only HTTP an Timer trigger options appears. I would like to work with CosmosDB and IoTHUB as triggers, input-output.
Any requirement that have been overlooked? Why do not I have more triggers options? Need guidance.

[image: HTTP and timer trigger as only options]

[image: option "More templates" do not appear on quick start]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you create a "httptrigger" function, you need to create Cosmos DB trigger by the template. Please refer to the steps below:
1. Click "+" --> "In-portal"
[image]

2.Click "More templates" --> "Finish and view templates"
[image]

3.Choose "Azure Cosmos DB trigger"
[image]

4.Click "Install"
[image]

5.Fill in the input box with your cosmos db details.
[image]

For further information, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function).

Comment: In my case, Javascript Azure function, in step 2 there is no "More templates" option... why? Cosmos DB trigger can't be used in a javascript Azure function?

Comment: Hi @smontoya Could you please provide a screenshot of your page which missing "More templates" ?

Comment: Hi @smontoya, I test it in my side. If we choose "linux" in the "Operating system"  when we create the function app, it will not show "More templates". Could you please create another function app and choose "windows" ?

Comment: You were right, with "windows" as "Operating system" all trigger options are available...This is a setback... anyway, question has been answered, so thanks.

Comment: @smontoya, I'm happy that you have solved this problem. Could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: A useful reference documentation about [Azure Functions portal editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#portal-editing) related to this case.